# Geoviews error : "Supplied data does not contain specified dimensions"

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas, holoviews, geoviews

When I try to plot Postgis Linestring, thanks to `gv.Path()` or `hvplot(geo=True)`, I have this error : `Supplied data does not contain specified dimensions, the following dimensions were not found: ['Longitude', 'Latitude']`.

```
sqla="Select Geography(ST_transform(traja,4326)) as traja, namea,nameb,mmsia,mmsib,p_dist,cpa_id from filtered where nm_a is not null and geometrytype(traja)='LINESTRING' limit 10"
gdf=gpd.read_postgis(sqla,con,geom_col='traja')
gdf.head()
```

[image: gdf.head()]

```
type(gdf['traja'][0])
----------------
shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString
```

When I try the visualization :

```
gdf.hvplot(geo=True)
----------------
DataError: Supplied data does not contain specified dimensions, the following dimensions were not found: ['Longitude', 'Latitude']

PandasInterface expects tabular data, for more information on supported datatypes see http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Tabular_Datasets.html
```

When I do `hvplot(geo=False)` it works but I would like to have a base map and benefit from all the Geoview's options.
Would someone have an idea ?

Comment: [please do not upload images of code, data, or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - they're not searchable and can't be read by screen readers. Instead, please post as a formatted code block. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoViews needs to know which of your data columns or dimensions should be used for latitude and longitude. I think you can either rename the data columns to "Longitude" and "Latitude", or you can tell GeoViews what the dimensions are named with something like `gv.Path(data, ['lon','lat'])`. There's probably a way to supply the names explicitly to hvPlot as well, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the data that I want to plot is contained in one column as it's a Postgis "Linestring" geometry, as you can see on the screenshot.

Comment: In that case you probably need to convert your PostGIS geometries into the Shapely geometries supported by GeoViews? See https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#interoperation , e.g.`geom = shapely.wkb.loads(hex_geom[0], hex=True)`

Comment: Must be that ! I will try and keep you in touch

Comment: I edited the post to make it more clear. Unfortunatly, it seems that my objects are already Shapely geometries as you can see with the `type()` line

Comment: Looks like GeoViews currently requires the geometry column to be named "geometry", so I'd try renaming `traja` to `geometry`.

Comment: Indeed that's what we talked about [here](https://github.com/holoviz/hvplot/issues/665), I close the issue as it works